# Suppose $u$ is continuous on $\overline{D_1(0)}$ and that $u(z)$ is defined below for each $z\in D_1(0)$. Prove that $u$ is harmonic in $D_1(0)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $u$ is continuous on $\overline{D_1(0)}$ and that
$$
u(z) = \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} u(z+(1-|z|)e^{i\theta})\,d\theta
$$
for each $z\in D_1(0)$. Prove that $u$ is harmonic in $D_1(0)$.

$u(z)$ almost has the form of the averaging property which I know to be harmonic. Is there a way to manipulate the given $u(z)$ to have the form of the averaging property?

Answer (score 1):

Let $v$ the harmonic function that coincides with $u$ on the circle of radius $1$ - the Poisson integral of $u(e^{i\theta})$.

Let $f=u-v$ and assume $f$ not identically zero. Since $f$ is zero on the unit circle by construction and is continuous on the closed unit disc, we can assume that its maximum is $f(z_0)=2a>0$ for some $0<|z_0|=r<1$ (if the maximum is zero, we use the minimum and same proof, while $f(0)=0$!).

The point $\frac{z_0}{r}$ is on the unit circle so there is a small neighbourhood of it in the disc for which $|f(z)|<a$, so in particular on the circle of center $z_0$ and radius $1-r$ which contains $\frac{z_0}{r}$ there is an arc where $|f|<a$.

Since $v$ satisfies the mean value property in general and $u$ satisfies it for the circle above, $f$ satisfies it for the circle above but $f$ at the centre is the maximum $2a$ while on the circle it is at most $a$ on an arc and $2a$ on the rest of the circle. Contradiction, so $f=0, u=v$ harmonic.